# Перенос данных из MongoDB в DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, dataframe, оптимизация

Есть ли красивый быстрый способ сделать так:

- В mongo есть коллекция "ингредиенты" - в ней только id и name, их количество фиксированно

```
 {_id: 1, name: "potatoes"},
 {_id: 2, name: "carrot"},
 {etc...}
```

- и есть коллекция "блюда", в которой в поле типа list хранятся id всех ингредиентов для данного блюда. Количество блюд в базе - не ограничено.

```
{_id:1,
name: "soup",
ingredients: [1, 2, 3]},
{_id:2,
name: "puree",
ingredients: [1, 4]},
```

Можно ли по-быстрому оптимизированными встроенными функциями сделать DataFrame, в котором колонками будут ингредиенты, индекс - названия блюд, и 0/1 в ячейках - в зависимости, есть или нет ингредиент в блюде - тип такого:

[image: тип того]

т.е. не `for each in db.collection.find()...` а по-нормальному...

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема? Все-таки, что значит "по-нормальному" и какие конкретно требования? Вопрос читается так: "Существует ли магия, которая решит мою специфическую задачу в одну строчку без регистрации и смс?".

Comment: @mrEvgenX `for each` кажется долгим решением, существуют ли какие-то встроенные методы в pandas, позволяющие сделать это на уровне матриц?

Comment: Кажется долгим или проводились измерения? Приложение зависает и подолгу не отдает ответ? Долгим по сравнению с чем? По аналогии с чем ищется решение, где есть "долгий" путь через цикл, а есть "по-нормальному" встроенным методом? Изучение документации ничего не дало https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/index.html? Ответы на эти вопросы помогут помочь, я сомневаюсь, что в такой формулировке вопроса на него возможно ответить.

Comment: Тем более, что встроенные методы часто внутри себя проходятся циклом. Хочется сэкономить процессорное время или время придумывания алгоритма и набора его на клавиатуре? Стоит ознакомиться с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask и с https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html).

Пример:

Исходный DF (думаю вам не составит труда создать такой DF):

```
In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   _id   name ingredients
0    1   soup   [1, 2, 3]
1    2  puree      [1, 4]
```

решение:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.pop('ingredients')),
                          columns=mlb.classes_,
                          index=df.index))
```

результат:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   _id   name  1  2  3  4
0    1   soup  1  1  1  0
1    2  puree  1  0  0  1
```

PS для того чтобы объединить две таблицы / коллекции в MongoDB, можно воспользоваться [mongojoin](https://pypi.org/project/mongojoin/)

Comment: you are genius! Thanks ❤️❤️❤️